# print a list: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 = 1 8 3 6 5 4 7 2 9

Tags: c, list

Given a single linked list with nodes containing an int and the next pointer.

The numbers in the odd positions are printed from left to right: 1 3 5 7 9 and the numbers in the even positions are printed from right to left: 8 6 4 2

and they are printed together like: odd-even-odd-even.., such that the result the function prints is: 1 8 3 6 5 4 7 2 9

This function has to be done recursively and without the use of an array or an auxiliary list in C language.

```
    void print(Node *lista,int actual, int length){
                if (actual<length)return;
                if (actual&1){
                    printf("%d",lista->value);
                    print(lista->next,actual+1,length-2);
                }else if(actual==length){
                    printf("%d",list->value);
                    print(list->next, actual+1, length);
                }
                print((lista->next)->next, actual+2, length);
            }
```

This is my attempt, which is wrong. I have done it iterative but I don't understand recursion enough. Don't focus on the syntax, just the idea..

(If its done without changing tha actual list would be better, i mean, just print in that order, the intention is not changing the list, just to print it)

Comment: (If its done without changing tha actual list would be better, i mean, just print in that order, the intention is not changing the list, just to print it)

Answer (score 1):

Here You have to take consider some things. I have a sample program which works fine for even number of series. [Here(ideone)](https://ideone.com/07F7AC) is the link.

The code is so complex, so in simple words you have to follow these steps:

> 1. You have to use a `static int count=0;` for this, when the count exceeds the limit then the `recursion` ends.
> 2. You have to consider all the scenarios, and according this you have to write their calling function with position.

You can take a look to the program for just an idea.

You can do in recursion like this way. It is just the idea of recursion logic.

```
void print(Node *lista, int pos, int length)
{
   static int count=0;
   if(count>=length)
         return;
   count++;
   //Place the if else conditions according to your position.
}
```

Comment: Er, have you forgotten to call the function recursively? This snippet also doesn't take care of the fact that odd (pair) values should be printed in the opposite order.

Comment: @MOehm sorry for the problem, is it okay now? please tell me.

Comment: @EugeneSh. why is it a problem? Is the answer wrong?

Comment: @EugeneSh. as you can see I am new so, I can't comment in the questions and clear my thoughts about the question. Sorry for that, I tried my best. I see the redundant code so I improvised it

Comment: The right answer should describe an algorithm for the question and some explanation that would be helpful for OP's learning. Just code would be pretty useless if the OP has a little understanding of what it does. The algorithm can be described  not necessarily with code, it can be some pseudocode or just steps. Let the OP do some work on coding. This is my opinion, and I would not downvote or flag this answer. But try to consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers :

1. If you print the value before calling the printing routine recursively, the values printed will be in the order you are starting with 
   i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...
2. If you are printing the values after the recursive call, the values will be printed in reverse order.
3. Jump twice to move to even and odd positions only.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use a split-merge technique. The append operation in a single linked list (SLL) takes O(n). It's thus always a more efficient idea to prepend to a SLL (which takes constant time) and then eventually reverse the SLL, which can be done in place in linear time with O(1) space. The overall complexity of this split-merge technique is thus O(n).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
int data;
struct Node* next;
} Node;

Node* makeNode(int data) {
Node* node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
node->data = data;
node->next = NULL;
return node;
}

void prepend(Node** head, int data) {
Node* newnode;
if (!*head) {
    *head = makeNode(data);
    return;
}
newnode = makeNode(data);
newnode->next = *head;
*head = newnode;
}

void print_list(Node* head) {
Node* p;
for (p = head; p; p = p->next) {
    printf("%d ", p->data);
}
printf("\n");
}

void reverse_sll(Node** head) {
Node *p, *q, *r;
p = NULL;
q = *head;
while (q) {
    r = q->next;
    q->next = p;
    p = q;
    q = r;
}
*head = p;
}

/* Reverse only the even positions (split-merge) */
Node* reverse_sll_evenpos(Node* head) {
Node *p, *oddList = NULL, *evenList = NULL, **q, *mergedList = NULL, *r;
int c = 0;

// Split the lists into odd, even
for (p = head; p; p = p->next, c++) {
    q = c%2 == 0? &oddList : &evenList;
    prepend(q, p->data);
}
reverse_sll(&oddList);

// Merge the two lists
p = oddList; r = evenList;
while (1) {
    if (p) {
        prepend(&mergedList, p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    if (r) {
        prepend(&mergedList, r->data);
        r = r->next;
    }
    if (!p && !r)
        break;
}

return mergedList;
}

int main() {
Node* head = NULL, *rev;
int i;
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    prepend(&head, i);

print_list(head);

rev = reverse_sll_evenpos(head);
print_list(rev);
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

My usage of pair and impair here are pair points to the element before the elements that should undergo swapping and so is impair.

The code works like this, First I it find the elements to swap,
I first find pair and impair, then the element's next references that should undergo swapping for suppose I am swapping element at position 2 pairNext will have element following 2 i.e. the 3rd element to patch the chain after swapping.

for example if I have `0 1 2 3 4`, if I just swap 1 and 3 I would end up with the list 1 3 4 because the 3's next element is 4. Therefore I not just swap the elements but also update the swapped `element->next` to the `elements->next` that existed before swapping.
I hope you are getting the idea, if not try removing the last two statements in the assignment statements in the else condition of the `printListValue` function.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct List{
        int value;
        struct List* next;
    };

    int main()
    {
        int i,length = 0;
        int max = 7;
        struct List* list = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
        struct List* head = list;
        for( i = 0; i< max; i ++)
        {
            list->value = i;
            struct List* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
            if(i < max - 1)
            list->next = temp;
            else
            list->next = NULL;
            list = temp;
        }
        list = head;
        while(list != NULL)
        {
            list = list->next;
            length++;
        }
        list = head;
        printListValue(list, length, 0);
        list = head;
        while(list != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\t",list->value);
            list = list->next;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int printListValue(struct List* list,int length, int position)
    {
        // position refers to the elements that I would like to swap
        if(position == length/2) //base condition of the recursive function
        {
            return 0;
        } 
        // choosing which position to skip swapping
        else if(position % 2 == 0 && position <= length/2)
        {
            printListValue(list, length, position + 1);
        }
        else // here we actually swap elements
        {
            int lastButN = length - position - 2;
            struct List* pair = list;
            struct List* pairNext;
            struct List* impair;
            struct List* impairNext;
            struct List* temp;
            int i = position - 1;

            while(i > 0)
            {
                pair = pair->next;
                i--;
            }
            //printf("after i\n");
            impair = list;
            while(lastButN > 0)
            {
                impair = impair->next;
                lastButN--;
            }
            // suppose I have 0 1 2 3 4 as list
            // and trying to sawpping 1 and 2
            temp = pair->next;
            pairNext = temp->next; // holding reference to 2  
            temp = impair->next;
            impairNext = temp->next; // holding reference to 4
            // here we are actually swapping the elements
            temp = pair->next;
            pair->next = impair->next;
            impair->next = temp;
            int y;
            for(y = 0 ; y < 1;y++)
            {
                pair = pair->next;
                impair = impair->next;
            }
            // updating new next values of new list to chainup the list properly
            pair->next = pairNext;
            impair->next = impairNext;
            printListValue(list, length, position + 1);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The following function will print only the required list instead of manipulating the list. Here `MAX` is the equal to size of the list.

```
    char* printList(struct List* list, int length)
    {
        static char PRINTSTRING[MAX];
        static int count = 0;
        if(length <= 0)
        {
            int y =0;
            printf("\n");
            while(y < MAX)
            printf("%3d",PRINTSTRING[y++]);
            return 0;
        }
        int first, second,i;
        first = list->value;
        struct List* temp = list;
        for(i=0;i<(length-1);i++)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        second = temp->value;
        if(count%2 == 0)
        {
            PRINTSTRING[count] = first;
            PRINTSTRING[MAX - count -1] = second;
        }
        else
        {
            PRINTSTRING[count] = second;
            PRINTSTRING[MAX - count -1] = first;
        }
        count++;
        printList(list->next, length-2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that code needs to traverse the entire list before the 2nd number may be printed.  So let code walk the entire list before printing anything.

To insure the solution of `O(n)`, as the link list is walked, recurse once each time building up a pair of linked-lists: *odd* and *even*.  Each recursion provides the space for the added odd/even element.  When code reaches the end-of the list, alternately print elements of the *odd* and *even* list.

A circular list (last element points to first element) is used for the *odd* list to facilitate appending to the end of the list and accessing the head in `O(1)`.

[Edit]
Simplified by only recursing N/2 times.

```
typedef struct intnode {
  struct intnode *next;
  int value;
} intnode;

void intnode_print_odd_even(const intnode *odd_end, const intnode *even) {
  const intnode *odd_begin = odd_end->next;
  const intnode *odd = odd_begin;
  for (;;) {
    printf("%d ", odd->value);
    odd = odd->next;
    if (even == NULL)
      return;
    printf("%d ", even->value);
    even = even->next;
    if (odd == odd_begin)
      return;
  }
}

void intnode_oddeven(const intnode *ll, intnode *odd_end, intnode *even) {
  if (ll) {
    intnode odd1;
    intnode even1;

    // Add odd element to the end of the odd list
    odd1.value = ll->value;
    if (odd_end) {
      odd1.next = odd_end->next;  // circular list
      odd_end->next = &odd1;
    } else {
      odd1.next = &odd1;  // circular list
    }

    ll = ll->next;
    if (ll) {
      // Add even element to the beginning of the even list
      even1.value = ll->value;
      even1.next = even;
      even = &even1;
      ll = ll->next;
    }
    intnode_oddeven(ll, &odd1, even);
  } else {
    intnode_print_odd_even(odd_end, even);
  }
}

void intnode_print(const intnode *ll) {
  intnode_oddeven(ll, NULL, NULL);
  printf("\n");
}

void testll() {
  intnode ll[9] = { { &ll[1], 1 }, { &ll[2], 2 }, { &ll[3], 3 }, { &ll[4], 4 },
      { &ll[5], 5 }, { &ll[6], 6 }, { &ll[7], 7 }, { &ll[8], 8 }, { NULL, 9 } };
  intnode_print(ll);
}

int main(void) {
  testll();
  return 0;
}
```

> Output: 1 8 3 6 5 4 7 2 9